# Installing Elasticsearch 5.0.2 on Windows 8 - \config\jvm.options "was unexpected at this time"

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm new to Stack Overflow (though a long time lurker).
I'm struggling to install elasticsearch on my laptop. It's windows 8, I've just updated java to Java 8 and I've set the new path using set JAVA_HOME.

However, whenever I try to run the elasticsearch.bat file on the command line, I get this error:

\elasticsearch-5.0.2\bin\..\config\jvm.options was unexpected at this time

Any help would be greatly appreciated on this matter

Answer (score 11):

I've also tried to setup the ElasticSearch on my Windows 2016 R2 Datacenter (64-bit). Let me share some of my experiences on how to solve this.

---

### Setting up JAVA_HOME

Ensure that you have JDK/JRE installed. You can download it [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-jsp-138363.html).

Set the JAVA_HOME environment variable. To do this, open the Start menu and type in "**path**".

[image: environment_variable]

Then click on **Environment Variables**. If you don't have **JAVA_HOME** variable set yet, click **New**.

[image: java_home]

The JAVA_HOME variable should only lead up to the JDK/JRE directory, not including /bin.

```
C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_112
```

**Progra~1** corresponds to **Program Files**. If you use **Program Files (x86)**, change **Progra~1** to **Progra~2**

Restart your computer. Once your computer is restarted, open up CMD and type in **echo %JAVA_HOME%**. The output should be

```
C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_112
```

If you get the following output, your **JAVA_HOME** is setup correctly.

---

### Running ElasticSearch

The first time I tried to run ElasticSearch, I get the following output.

[image]

The odd directory I pointed out here gave me a hint that the batch file might be reading from the wrong directory. So what I did was tinker around with the batch file a bit. Open **elasticsearch.bat** using any text editor.

Scroll all the way to the end, somewhere above the last lines you'll see something similar to the following.

[image: wrong path]

Remove the highlighted line, save the file and try running the batch file again via command prompt.

It works in my case.

[image: run]

Once you have this, open up your browser and navigate to **localhost:9200**.

[image: localhost]

I think that's it?

Comment: I've been searching high and low for 4 days for step by step instructions specific to windows machines. Thanks man +1

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is most likely caused by parentheses in the path to where you unzipped and are running Elasticsearch from. The related issue in the Elasticsearch repository is [#24712](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/24712) which will be fixed with Elasticsearch 5.4.1.

Be aware that by applying Nicholas Lie's "fix" you are telling Elasticsearch to effectively ignore all settings in `config/jvm.options`. While this may help you to start Elasticsearch in this specific case, it will only start with default JVM options which might lead to surprising behavior down the road.